# Identifying GoogleBot: why reverse AND forward DNS checks?

Tags: security, dns, googlebot

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en

To identify GoogleBot crawler HTTP requests Google recommend doing a reverse DNS look up on the request IP address to check domain name is Google's.

But why do they then ask you to do a forward DNS check? Is this more secure? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article Google suggests to run both a reverse and forward DNS check.

With the reverse DNS lookup you get a FQDN associated with the IP. However, anybody with the ability to manage reverse DNS for an IP can potentially return a fake name containing googlebot.com on it.

However, if you get the result of the first DNS query and you perform a forward DNS, it will likely not pass the second test as the `googlebot.com` zone is managed by Google and the owner of the original IP can't create a record in that zone.